# How to use a report as subreport (with additional info) multiple times in a maintainable way?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

So basically I have a report. I need this report to be printed as a 'set of reports'. Except that for each time the report is printed, there has to be a specific numbering at the bottom of the page. Where it would look something like this:
**Page 1:** Report + Page footer text 'Number 1'
**Page 2:** Conditions
**Page 3**: Report + Page footer text 'Number 2'
**Page 4:** Conditions
**Page 5:** Report + Page footer text 'Number 3'
**Page 6:** Conditions
And so on, for an undetermined amount of times..

In order to achieve this, I have created a main report, which currently contains 20 subreports, in order to achieve 20 pages (but I really I'd like this to be dynamical, maybe to be able to set the number of copies or something). Where each subreport consists of the single mentioned report (through the subreport 'Choose an existing report' option), with a custom text at the bottom.

The problem with this is that **I can't maintain this**. Every time an adjustment needs to be made to the original report, I will need to access 10 subreports and make the very same change or reload the report into this subreport.

What alternative ways of achieving my goal can you suggest, because this feels really 'dirty'. Thank you for reading.

I run Version 14.0.2.364 of Crystal Reports 2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to use group and detail section in main report. For making adjustments with paging, each section has his own

- page before
- page after
- reset page

[image]

So to help you a bit, you need to have your data in one datasource, and group by
Report/Conditions. For each group you can have only 1 subreport which will have link for that specific subreport (e.g. where barcod of smth is 1234) and there show your subreport data. For page number i would advise you to use my approach (for grouping) and then for page number you display group number (and that solves you all formulas for calculating pages).

If you are not familiar with grouping in Crystal, you can group your records in report by some fields by following image below

[image]

To summarize, try to define by which fields your reports has 20 subreports (probably some keys from database) and then group by that fields, examine advances of section expert and paging and you should be done in few hours making your report readable and easy to maintain.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate response. It's still unclear to me how I prevent having to maintain multiple subreports (1 per group) based on your explanation. For the record, the data shown in the subreport will be loaded from an existing report. Thus whenever this existing report is being adjusted, I will have to make this adjustment for each subreport. Perhaps I'm just not fully aware of the 3 section expert options (page before/after, reset page) you mention. I will definitely try this out. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. If your subreports have different outputs and different datasources then you won't be able to do this which i suggested you. But if they are same but with different data then you could simplify things a lot.

Comment: It's the very same subreport, just with some specific text/page numbering added to it in the footer.

Comment: Then you should be able to do what i wrote above :)